# Spilled shampoo on floor and it has dried up

Tags: cleaning

I have a laundry basket next to my washing machine. Since there is no shelf near the washing machine I tend to keep all detergent bottles and other laundry needs in the laundry basket itself and dump clothes on to top of it. I remember putting in a shampoo bottle that I thought I'd later use to wash some of my delicates. The shampoo was not serving its purpose as shampoo because it made my hair dry. The shampoo bottle at some point tipped inside the laundry basket and leaked all over floor. I had parked my bicycle near the washing machine (yep apartment house small space adjustments this) and shampoo leaked through the basket, spread underneath the cycle tire.

One day I decided to clear the floor and moved my cycle without noticing that the tire just spread all the partially dried sticky shampoo all over the floor. Cleaning it with a wet towel just made the work worse.

How do I clean up sticky partially dried shampoo from floor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wash with water. Blot dry. Repeat, repeat *ad nauseam*. Shampoo contains detergent, and from your description, " it made my hair dry," a *lot* of it.

The good news is that plain water should completely remove the shampoo, other than any colorant, and that will be the cleanest spot on *any* floor, but the bad news is that even a bit of leftover detergent makes a lot of foam, and that every used towel must be washed. Murphy's Law Corollary, ["Conservation of Filth: In order for something to get clean, something else must get dirty, [but] it is possible for everything to get dirty and nothing to get clean.](http://www.murphys-laws.com/murphy/murphy-laws.html)"

If it's any consolation, spilled concentrated liquid laundry detergent requires more rinsing yet.

Comment: I would definitely use paper towels. You'll likely go through a large number of them, but the time saved in not washing out the towel every time is huge.

Answer (score 1):

If it is dried and in a somewhat solid form, you could use a nylon scraper ([http://www.amazon.com/Favorite-Nylon-Pan-Scraper-Set/dp/B00U93NU3W/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&qid=1450732638&sr=8-16](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U93NU3W)) to get most of it off the floor. I have these scrapers for cleaning pots and pans. They are great because they don't scratch surfaces very easily. Once you get most of it off the floor, hopefully you'll only need 1 towel to wash the floor. Best of luck!